# Computing the analytic $p$-adic $L$-function via modular symbols in MAGMA

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory, magma-cas, l-functions

I need to compute the analytic $p$-adic $L$-function of an elliptic curve at a prime $p$ via modular symbols using `MAGMA`. In `SAGE` this is `E.padic_lseries(p).series(n)` where `n` is the precision to which the series is computed. So please give me the code for `MAGMA`.

Comment: Perhaps this [Magma handbook page](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1555#17013) about the `pAdicLSeries` function helps.

Comment: @ccorn Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no code to solve this problem distributed with Magma as standard. Your choices are: use the Sage implementation; implement the algorithms in Magma for yourself; or find someone who has appropriate Magma code and persuade them to share it with you.

EDIT. This answer is totally wrong, as ccorn's comment above shows. I had apparently been looking at an old version of the Magma handbook. Ignore what I said and follow the link in the comment.